# Get a value inside a SPAN on change event for jQuery UI accordion element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the value of a SPAN when user change the active header element and also trigger a $.ajax call. I have this code: http://pastebin.com/rxQRSADQ and the value I get on change event is the value contained in the SPAN with class: selected-center-open-ticket-label but I just need the number "1" and not the entire value meaning "Ticket: 1". Can any help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is consistently "Ticket: " then you can use `substr(8)`.

**EDIT:**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/6dkh6/

jQuery:

```
$('.selected-center-open-ticket').click(function() {
    alert($(this).find(".selected-center-open-ticket-label").text().substr(8));
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tickets-accordion">
    <div class="selected-center-open-ticket">
        <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/admin/icon/icon2.png" alt="Close" title="Close" class="max-icon" width="21" height="17" /></a>
        <img src="/assets/img/admin/foto-2.jpg" alt="Username" title="Username"
        class="avatar" />
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-label">Ticket: 1</span>
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-store">La Trinidad</span>
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-user">Reynier Perez Mira</span>
    </div>
    <div class="selected-center-open-ticket">
        <a href="#"><img src="/assets/img/admin/icon/icon2.png" alt="Close" title="Close" class="max-icon" width="21" height="17" /></a>
        <img src="/assets/img/admin/foto-2.jpg" alt="Username" title="Username"
        class="avatar" />
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-label">Ticket: 2</span>
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-store">Boleíta</span>
        <span class="selected-center-open-ticket-user">Reynier Perez Mira</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Hmmm yes it's consistent but my question is more to ask when to fire the event and get the value, something like: $('.selected-center-open-ticket').click(function(){}) is that right?

Comment: Ok @a-m-k I'm waiting so to test the demo and see if what I'm looking for, thanks by the way

Comment: Nice and many thanks @a-m-k this is what I'm looking for and also thanks to Ricardo

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left-hand side of my answer.

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/6dkh6/3/. It just gets anything past the first 8 characters.

Comment: But you have to have a static string, rigth? You can change to `$(".selected-center-open-ticket-label", this).text().substr(8);`

Comment: What else can there be in an HTML element? P.S. Forgot about `, this` in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

How about a `regexp` matching numbers ?

```
var string = "Ticket11: 1".match(/\d+$/)[0];
alert(string);
```

This way you can pass any string, like my example, and it'll return the last numbers.

`\d` matches digits.
`+` matches one or more.
`$` matches the end of string.

**[matches demos](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Kee/)**

Comment: Ok, ricardo-lohmann but how to find the value in the SPAN? Any JS extra is required to get the value inside the span or should I do this: alert($('selected-center-open-ticket-label').val().match(/\d+$/)[0]) and nothing else?

Comment: @ReynierPM When your selector is a class you have to use `.` like $('.selected-center-open-ticket-label').val().match(/\d+$/)[0]

Comment: I get this error when try your code: TypeError: $(".selected-center-open-ticket-label").val().match(/\d+$/) is null

alert($('.selected-center-open-ticket-label').val().match(/\d+$/)[0]);

Comment: @ReynierPM Use `text` instead of `val` like this `$('.selected-center-open-ticket-label').text().match(/\d+$/)[0];`

Comment: @ReynierPM You can't get text of `spans` using `val`

Comment: @ReynierPM You're welcome, I added a demo which you can see some cases that you can see the test.

Comment: I'm using your solution in fact because is more robust that the one suggested by AMK as I said both works fine!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14547/discussion-between-ricardo-lohmann-and-reynierpm)